# 2D Arraylist Error

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors, bluej

I've successfully created a 2D Arraylist but I still am having issues storing my values into the Arraylist. My error message is as follows, "cannot find symbol - method add(int,java.lang.String). I know its probably a simple fix but I couldn't find it online or anywhere in my textbook. And I also am wondering if there is a simpler way to create a 2D arraylist. Thanks.

Here is where I declare the 2D array:

`ArrayList <ArrayList<String>> account = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()`;

Here is my code:

```
public void newAccount()
{
    firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your first name?");
    nLastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your last name?");
    nAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current address?");
    nCity= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current city?");
    nState = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current State?");
    nZipCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current Zip Code?");
    account.add( accountNumber, firstName);
    account.add( accountNumber, nLastName);
    account.add( accountNumber, nAddress);
    account.add( accountNumber, nCity);
    account.add( accountNumber, nState);
    account.add(accountNumber, nZipCode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is to use object instead of Strings:

```
ArrayList <Account> account = new ArrayList<Account>();
```

And this is the Account class:

```
public class Account{
    public String firstName;
    public String nLastName;
    public String nAddress;
    public String nCity;
    public String nState;
    public String nZipCode; 
}
```

And addition to list:

```
public void newAccount()
{
    Account a = new Account();

    a.firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your first name?");
    a.nLastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your last name?");
    a.nAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current address?");
    a.nCity= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current city?");
    a.nState = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current State?");
    a.nZipCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current Zip Code?");

    account.add(a);
}
```

You can change visibility and use it with setter/getter. This is just to explain you the example.

Comment: I have a loop so I can create as many accounts as I would like, would this code overlap the previous account?

Comment: No. You add each time a new one to `account`. Also `a` is valid only in called method. If you call it multiple times, then you have multiple objects, that will be added to `account`. Try it out :)

Comment: Thank you so much, you probably saved me another 4 hours of looking on the web :)

Answer (score 0):

You should first create an `ArrayList<String>` and add your Strings to this `ArrayList`.Then add this `ArrayList` to your `account` `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont want an array list of strings, you want an array list of Account Information, like so:

```
 class AccountEntry{
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public int address, city, state, zipCode;
 }

 ArrayList<AccountEntry> accounts = new ArrayList<AccountEntry>();

 AccountEntry entry = new AccountEntry();
 entry.firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your first name?");
 //..and so on
 accounts.add( entry ); //add the account
```